# Loading a ListView with a List of Objects containing attributes do not set BackgroundColor as it should

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

Sorry for the inaccuracy of the title, but I could not describe my issue better. If someone has a better and more precise title, I would like to know. Thank you.

In an app, I am making using Xamarin.Forms with Prism there is a certain page containing a `ListView` whose the items have some data and a Button. I load from an API an `ObservableCollection` of `MyObject`, where I have some properties defining labels and styles of my list items. This list is reloaded every time I refresh it or I click on one of the item's buttons. When a button is clicked it calls an API that updates some properties including the item's button background color.

My problem is that sometimes the button color is not updated on the screen. My property is set right and even the "clicked" color is right, but the color of the button itself is not. At least in the first sight, if the item is scrolled away and back on, there is a change that it changes to the right color.

My `ObservableCollection<MyObject>`is bid into the `ListView`'s ItemsSource and my `Button` `BackgroundColor` attribute is set `{Binding ButtonColor}` I tried to inherit `MyObject` from `INotifyPropertyChanged` and it did not change a thing. I already checked multiple times whether the color is right in the code is set right and it always was.

MyObject:

```
      public class MyObject
      {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Value { get; set; }
            public string Status { get; set; }  
            public string BackgroundColor { get; set; }
            public string ButtonColor { get; set; }  
            public string ButtonText { get; set; }
       }
```

My ListView:

```
      <ListView 
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            ItemsSource="{Binding MyObjectList}"
            IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
            RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshListCommand}"
            IsRefreshing="{Binding IsLoading}" 
            HasUnevenRows="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell >
                        <Grid 
                            RowSpacing="0"
                            BackgroundColor="{Binding BackgroundColor}">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="3" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="3" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1.3*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Label 
                                Text="{Binding Value"
                                Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"/>
                            <Button
                                Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"
                                Text="{Binding ButtonText}"
                                BackgroundColor="{Binding ButtonColor}"
                                Clicked="Update_Clicked"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

My Commands (the `Update_Clicked` executes the `UpdateCommand` passing the selected item's id)

```
      private ObservableCollection<MyObject> _myObjectList;
      public ObservableCollection<MyObject> MyObjectList
      {
          get => _myObjectList;
          set => SetProperty(ref _myObjectList, value);
      }

        private DelegateCommand _refreshListCommand;
        public DelegateCommand RefreshListCommand=>
            _refreshListCommand?? (_refreshListCommand= new DelegateCommand(ExecuteRefreshListCommand));

      private async void ExecuteRefreshListCommand()
      {
           MyObjectList?.Clear();
           var serviceReturn = await _myService.GetObjectList();//Returns a ordered by Status (Stopped, ToBegin, Started) List of MyObject with properties depending on its status (they all are born with the ToBegin Status
           MyObjectList =  new ObservableCollection<MyObject>(serviceReturn )
      }

        private DelegateCommand<int?> _updateCommand;
        public DelegateCommand<int?> UpdateCommand=>
            _updateCommand?? (_updateCommand= new DelegateCommand<int?>(ExecuteUpdateCommand));

      private async void ExecuteUpdateCommand(int? id)
      {
           await _myService.UpdateToNextStatus(id); //Changes the object's status and its properties to the next in a cicle ToBegin -> Started -> Stopped -> Started -> ...
           ExecuteRefreshListCommand()
      }
```

MyObject has 3 possible states according to its Status:

```
Status = "ToBegin"
BackgroundColor = "#fff"
ButtonColor = "#00ff00"
ButtonText = "Start"

Status = "Started"
BackgroundColor = "#aaa"
ButtonColor = "#ff0000"
ButtonText = "Stop"

Status = "Stopped"
BackgroundColor = "#fff"
ButtonColor = "#ff0000"
ButtonText = "Restart"
```

The thing with it is that everything updates nicely, the grid's background color, the button text... but eventually after some rounds of changing status from Started to Stopped and Stopped to Started **with a ToBegin in the list**, the list seems to lose how it should display the button and it shows with the wrong color, even after refreshing a couple more times it does not work.

Comment: you need to read up on the different caching modes of ListView

Comment: Can you share the code in `UpdateToNextStatus()`?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT this api simply changes the object to the next set of properties in my database. I don't have access to it, but I can assure it works. My problem is in the screen, not in the background as I mentioned.

Comment: You have to check if you are changing the data in MyObjectList in method `UpdateToNextStatus()`.

Comment: I can assure I am @JackHua-MSFT

Comment: @Jason, your solution worked! Using `CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"` as a `ListView` property made the deal.